# Parsing a column from json format in pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe where one of the columns is a json format like shown below:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- row_number: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- json: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- @timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- @version: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- beat: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- hostname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- host: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- input: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- message: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- prospector: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- station: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

I am interested in the `message` column within the json format that is a very large string of logs. The message column has its own schema that I parsed using pandas. For example, it has elements like #columns, #rows, #blocked, #rule, #process_duration etc that have  `#` in front of it that I identify as parts of the schema. 
Using pandas I was able to separate them out and arrange them into readable columns, but I need to do this over a very large data set, and my EC2 instance keeps crapping out. In any case, I dont think it is efficient to convert a spark dataframe to pandas and then back to spark again. 
My python pandas code was like:

```
y = json.loads(x[0])
col_names = pand.read_csv(StringIO(y["message"]), nrows = 1, skiprows=[0, 1], sep =' ', header=None,quotechar='\'', index_col=False)
dispatch_list=pand.read_csv(StringIO(y["message"]), sep=' ', header=None,
                                         comment='#', skiprows=[1], quotechar='\'',
                                         names = col_names.iloc[0 , 2:].tolist(),
                                         index_col=False)
```

I basically want to do what my pandas code is doing but using pyspark.
Is this possible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You

Update with sample data in the message column:

```
#headers 
'STATION: Harlem     MOVEABLE LOTS:  5 QTY:    0     HELD LOTS:   0 QTY:    0     BLOCKED LOTS:   0 QTY:    0'
#columns  'TargetEQP' 'GRank' 'LRank' 'Priority' 'Lot ID' 'Carrier ID' 'Auto Reason This Eqp' 'Full Auto Reason Target Eqp' 'Carrier Eqp ID' 'Carrier Station ID' 'Carrier Xfer Status' 'Reservation' 'Qty' 'Cond Type' 'PD ID' 'Oper Name' 'Oper No' 'Lot Processing State' 'Product ID' 'Machine Recipe ID' 'Ch_Comb_This_Eqp' 'Ch_Avail_This_Eqp'  'Multi Lot Type' 'Hold State' 'Route ID' 'Process RunSize Maximum' 'Sub Lot Type' 'Age' 'WI' 'SS' 'Time to Q Expr' 'Rush' 'Due Date' 'Due Date Source' 'Allowed Tools' 'Full Auto Reason This Eqp' 'TargetStocker' 'TargetPort' 'Processing Time' 'Addl Rework' 'Asset Owner' 'pass_count'
#widths  12 3 12 12 6 8 12 12 12 12 2 12 3 12 5 12 6 12 12 1 12 12 12 12 12 3 6 12 1 6 12 3 12 12 3 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 1
#types 'STRING' 'INTEGER' 'INTEGER' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'INTEGER' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'INTEGER' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'REAL' 'REAL' 'STRING' 'INTEGER' 'INSTANT' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'STRING' 'INTEGER' 
#lotcol -1
#rows
'Eqp1' '1' '1' 'Slow' 'LOT ID1' '6C20' 'N: QualEqp,EIProblem,NoAutoPorts' 'N: QualEqp(QualEqpId script parm is Eqp2),EIProblem(Eqp not in sync:  NOTINSYNCH),NoAutoPorts(Eqp has no online nor offline ports)' '' 'ZFG1' 'SI' '' '1' '' 'Recipe1' 'Recipe_Stem_1' '1000.1000' 'Waiting' 'Recipe_Stem_2' '' 'Recipe 2' 'Logical Recipe 2' '' '' '' 'ML-MR' 'NOTONHOLD' 'Recipe_Core' '1' 'Equipment Monitor' '0hr 51m' '1.3' '-153.1' '' '8' '12/15/18 02:41:42' 'Blocked PRD WIP' 'Block:Eqp1' 'N: QualEqp(QualEqpId script parm is Eqp2),EIProblem(Eqp not in sync:  NOTINSYNCH),NoAutoPorts(Eqp has no online nor offline ports)' '' '' '0' '' '' '1' 
#blocked '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' 
#rule 'NofM'
#station 'Harlem'
#station_type 'STATION'
#queue_duration '1.50204'
#process_duration '11.431'
```

Here the elements in the #column object should correspond with the elements in the  #rows object.
For example the column `TargetEQP` should have `Eqp1` under it and column `Priority` should have `Slow` under it and so on.

Comment: can you pls provide sample data for message column.

Comment: Added sample data.Thank you